# How to improve the sound when using Skype 2.2.0.35 on 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, skype, macbook

I have a MacBookPro 5.3 equipped with Ubuntu 10.10 on which I have repeatedly tried to use Skype but the result is disappointing: 
(a) while I can hear and talk (only when enabling PulseAudio), the quality of the sound is very very poor; 
(b) each call to a phone number is duplicated; 
(c) I have to manually kill Skype to exit the program.

In the past six months, I have tried various solutions found on the forums but with no satisfactory outcome.

Answer (score 1):

About the sound I might help you:

open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t)

type in `alsamixer`

I think you got at least these options: Master, Headphone, PCM, Front Speaker, Surround.

Set all of these options on max: arrow up until its at 100% ; arrow right for selecting the next option.

When you have set all these options, your sound should be better. Press 'esc' to exit the alsamixer settings.

To save your settings, type in `sudo alsactl store`.

When the wrong settings are loaded at boot time, just restore your settings with `alsactl restore`.

Comment: thanks, I tried playing with alsamixer when those problems started but this does not work...